# Opel Vectra A 1994 Service/Repair Manual

Tags: opel, service-manual, vectra

yes, it's a tired buddy, not from exploring the roads but from the previous owners' behavior.There is not any authorized repair shop in my country and i give up on spending for nothing.

I feel like a ghost because after more than one month of contacting different branches of the opel company i didn't received any reply. i even contacted some repair manual publishers, but no luck on receiving even a reply. There was just vauxhall of England that apologized because they couldn't help in any aspect.

I've searched the web a lot but i couldn't find anything related to the car. just some chapters of a manual not the entire manual in cardiagn.com that didn't have the exact engine that this buddy has, it was just close to it.
the Vin plate has a weird number and the engine code section is just 0000 but i guess it's a 2.0 150HP and the top speed is 220 KM/h. i don't know what to do, and i don't have any other option except trying to repair it myself, so any advice appreciated.

peace

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 for your reply. As i mentioned, because of the absence of a authorized repair shop and the previous worst owners, i have problem with different parts of the car time to time. That's why i looked for a repair manual to start repairing as much as i can.

Comment: Unfortunately, that makes this a shopping question, which puts it as off-topic for the site. If you need to, you can talk to us on [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) which is the site's chat room. It has a lot more flexibility than does the Q&A part.

Answer (score 0):

Haynes in the UK publishes an [aftermarket service manual](https://haynes.com/en-gb/opel/vectra/1988-1995) for your vehicle.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSupportsMonica. I've contacted them, unfortunately they only have the printed version, not any digital manual of the car and also not any reseller in the country that i apparently live. And fortunately :) because of the sanctions and weird situations in the country, I'm not saying it's impossible, but it's pretty difficult to buy a printed version by post. (DHL? TNT? FEDEX? UPs? ... we don't have them) so... You know, it's a beautiful life, oh oh oooh

Comment: I've done it. It's not difficult at all, if your country has mail service. Haynes will mail the manual internationally. Click through from the "Buy" link and you should see the option.